# JavaScript returning [object, Object]

Tags: jquery, json, youtube-api

I'm trying to use jQuery to parse some JSON from the Youtube API, here's my code so far:

```
// these are defined in my real code
var ajaxURL = URL + UserName + jsonFormat;

var myObject = JSON.stringify(ajaxURL);

$.getJSON(ajaxURL, function(data){
     var htmlString = "";

    $.each(data.data.items, function(i,item){       
        // Here's where we piece together the HTML
        htmlString += '<img src="';
        htmlString += item.thumbnail;
        htmlString += '">';
    });

    // Pop our HTML in the #image DIV
    $('#image').html(htmlString);

});
```

The JSON looks like(this has been cut down):

```
"data": {
        "updated": "2013-09-09T18:48:57.730Z",
        "totalItems": 1,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "itemsPerPage": 1,
        "items": [{
            "id": "theID",
            "uploaded": "2013-09-05T13:48:53.000Z",
            "updated": "2013-09-05T13:49:23.000Z",
            "uploader": "username",
            "category": "People",
            "title": "the title",
            "description": "the description",
            "thumbnail": {
                "sqDefault": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/erferfr/default.jpg",
                "hqDefault": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/erferfr/hqdefault.jpg"
            },
```

I have tried `.item.thumbnail[0]` but this still doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated - rather new to JSON!

Comment: did you try `item.thumbnail.sqDefault` ?

Comment: try `item.thumbnail["sqDefault"]`

Comment: @SB - perfect - please put this as an answer so I can accept. Thought I was on the right lines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access your data via `item.thumbnail.sqDefault` and `item.thumbnail.hqDefault` since it's an object w/ named props.